# Can I use the Samurai fighter's Fighting Spirit feature to make a Sneak Attack if I am also multiclassed into rogue?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, multi-classing, fighter, sneak-attack

I'm thinking about playing a fallen samurai in a D&D 5e campaign.

If the character multiclasses into rogue, can the Samurai fighter's Fighting Spirit feature be used to trigger the rogue feature Sneak Attack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes. Fighting Spirit gives you advantage, letting you Sneak Attack.

The Rogue's [Sneak Attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue#SneakAttack-343) feature says:

> Once per turn, you can deal an extra 1d6 damage to one creature you hit with an attack if you have advantage on the attack roll. The attack must use a finesse or a ranged weapon.

Since the [Samurai fighter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#Samurai)'s [Fighting Spirit](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#FightingSpirit-692) feature (XGtE, p. 31) gives you advantage on the attack roll, it will allow you to add Sneak Attack damage, as long as you're using a finesse or ranged weapon.

Fighting Spirit specifies weapon attack rolls, but doesn't restrict itself to melee weapons - this works just as well with a bow as a shortsword.

Comment: That's what I thought it just seems like it makes it too easy for a rogue to get a sneak attack.

Comment: @Adenine2k But you need to put three levels into fighter, so not so easy! Although I usually find it's pretty easy to get sneak attack anyway...

Comment: @Adenine2k a rogue should be getting sneak attack 90%+ anyway. Having an ally within 5 feet of the target is almost a given.

Comment: I almost addressed that in the answer, but I decided to keep it simple! Losing three levels of sneak attack progression and competing for the bonus action isn't nothing, and the fact that it's a limited number of uses per day mean I think it's far from broken.